# Back button takes too long to go back - Possible reasons?

Tags: android, delay, lag

So I have a menu screen activity which calls other activities like so

```
option = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OptionsScreen.class);  

...  

startActivity(option);
```

This options screen so far does nothing. more specifically, it is:

```
public class OptionsScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
    Toast.makeText(OptionsScreen.this, "options", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And that's the whole activity for now.  I call other Activities in a similar way.  **When I hit back it consistently takes 5 seconds to go back to the menu screen.**  This should not take this long since the OnResume() does nothing but set up onclick listeners. edit: On the MOTODEV emulators it freezes (might be a different problem) and on the basic android emulator it runs the same way as on the phone (5 second delay).
possibly relevant - When the menu screen is first called it plays a 5 second video, then uses a ViewSwitcher to go to the menu.  that video only plays when the app first runs.

**What are some possible reasons for this delay?** Any ideas would be much appreciated.

EDIT: the following is the code from the OnCreate() function which plays the video.  I actually removed it and it did not fix the delay, but I'll post it anyway.

```
VideoView logo;
...

logo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://COM.PRACTICE/" + R.raw.logoanimation2));
    logo.requestFocus();
    logo.start();
    logo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(UpdateTimeTask);
            mSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcherMenu);
            mSwitcher.showNext();
            menushown = true;
            logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                };
            });
        }
    });
```

EDIT: ok, so When I put "mSwitcher.showNext();" at the beginning of OnResume, it goes back with no delay, and plays the video again.  I guess there is something I need to do to instantly show the correct view in the viewSwitcher? Anyone know what that is?

EDIT: I partially solved this problem.  The delay is gone for 2/3 of the activities I launch from it.  I did this in an odd way and I would still like to understand it better.  I added the following code to the Onresume():

```
if (menushown) {mSwitcher.showNext(); mHandler.postDelayed(ViewSwitcherTask, 100);}
```

and then add this to the Activity Class:

```
Runnable ViewSwitcherTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       mSwitcher.showNext();
    }
 };
```

Simply calling showNext() twice did not work, and neither did anything else i tried.  This is obviously not the ideal solution. Why would it work on 2/3 of my screens? Does anyone know why I had to do this?  What is a better way to fix this delay?

EDIT: I simply removed the videoview from the view switcher after it plays. Fixed the problem completely.

Comment: Activate the logCat and you can see more detailed why you are getting the ANR message, maybe the Stream of your video doesn't stop whe you change to another activity...

Comment: the ANR only happened on the motodev AVDs that i downloaded, which just don't seem to be working right (so not sure if that was worth mentioning) they freeze when the screen opens and the toast text never goes away even after hitting home (the back button is non-responsive).  Anyway, on the working emulator, nothing unusual shows in LogCat when I hit back(just a ~5 second delay). just the free memory stuff that comes up often. Thanks though.

Comment: Is it precisely a 5 second delay? If so, I would guess that the thread -- or however you're running the video -- is still running (or sleeping), even though the video doesn't play. Could you post that code so we can check it as well?

Comment: I just timed it repeatedly, and it seems to be exactly 5 seconds, for every screen. the video is exactly 5 seconds. seems like a non-coincidence.

Comment: I actually commented out the last code section that i just included in my question (replacing it with a Runnable on a 10 second delay) and there was still a 5 second delay when hitting back.

Comment: Just curious - have you tried setting/checking a static flag indicating whether or not the video has played (or been started) once before?

Comment: no. (unfamiliar with static flags) I simply only play it from the OnCreate of the first Activity, and it ran correctly, so I did nothing else.  Since the OnCreate is called only at the start up of the application, I don't know how the video could be causing this (only going back); I only mentioned it because the delay was the same length as the video.  I am still new to android development though, so who knows.